# Is it possible to draw a 2 parameter bifurcation diagram for a 2 dimensional system by hand?

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

Is it possible to draw a 2 parameter bifurcation diagram by hand or using only python? (without using software like AUTO) What would the steps involved be? 
How do you find the equation of a saddle node bifurcation line?

I want to reproduce a figure from a paper and I can't get my head around using AUTO so I would like to draw the figure by hand or using python.

I have not been able to find any good examples online for 2 parameter bifurcation diagrams.

[Figure 2 from Chaotic Attractor in the Kuramoto model Maisstrenko 2005](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNmXU.png)
This is the figure I am trying to reproduce.

[image]

These are the equations of the 2 dimensional system.

\begin{align*} \dot{\varphi}_1 &= \Delta_1+\frac{K}{3}[\sin(\varphi_2)-\sin(\varphi_1+\varphi_2)-2\sin(\varphi_1)] \\ \dot{\varphi}_2 &= \Delta_2+\frac{K}{3}[\sin(\varphi_1)-\sin(\varphi_1+\varphi_2)-2\sin(\varphi_2)] \end{align*}

Comment: Hi Moo, thank you for your response. I have added the figure that I am trying to reproduce and the equations. Would I be able to draw that figure using just python? I really just want to draw the 3 saddle node bifurcation curves B1, B2 and B3. Or would I need to use AUTO to draw it?

Comment: thank you very much. do you have a link to any example that would be helpful?

Comment: Btw, [Doedel's slides](http://indy.cs.concordia.ca/auto/notes.pdf) could be very useful here. It's basically how AUTO works inside (except few tricks maybe). You can reproduce these bits in Python if you use NumPy and SciPy. Also in your case [PyDSTool](http://www2.gsu.edu/~matrhc/PyCont.html#head-1f446b2c91f29a961110905b9bcd330d417a6eeb) might be enough, since you want compute only saddle-node bifurcations: PyDSTool has PyCont which should be easier than AUTO (it's a sort of interface), but has limited capabilities.

Comment: Also, maybe [this guide](http://www2.mat.dtu.dk/people/F.Schilder/rauto/node9.html) will help your understand AUTO better :)